# Pearson's Correlation on high throughput micrroarray data

Tags: correlation, bioinformatics

I am working in bioinformatics. I am using a microarray data of 24000 genes (attribute) and 170 samples. Is it possible to find Pearson's correlation of 24000 attributes?

Comment: Yes, question is why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use R's function 'cor' to get a matrix of correlation coefficients for every pairwise comparison. Default is PCC but there are options for non-parametric methods too. However, 'cor' will not provide you with P-values. To get these, you will need to use 'cor.test' individually for each pairwise comparison. Alternatively, you could use permutation methods to obtain null distribution of the test statistics and get P-values as it is done in the case of randomization tests.